# ldap.INVALID_DN_SYNTAX error when I try to create an AD user with python ldap

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I have an error when I try to create a new user in my active directory with python ldap. The connection to the server works since the search function works.
Here is my code, I apologize in advance if several elements are mixed up, I have tried a lot of things since different tutorial:

```
    import ldap
    import ldap.modlist as modlist


    ldap_client = ldap.initialize('ldap://serverName')
    ldap_client.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    ldap_client.simple_bind_s('root@domain', 'password')
    baseDN = "OU=ou_where_create,OU=users,OU=tree_of_ou,OU=FIM,DC=domain,DC=LAN"
    sam = 'TTEST'
    cn = "TEST Toto"
    sn = "TEST"
    givenname = "Toto"
    mail = "TTEST"
    userPrincipalName = 'TTEST@fim-online.net'
    name = "TEST Toto"
    displayName = "TEST Toto"
    # user_dn = 'CN=' + sn + ' ' + givenname + ',' + baseDN
    user_dn = "CN=TOTOTest,OU=ou_where_create,OU=users,OU=tree_of_ou,OU=FIM,DC=domain,DC=LAN"

    user_attrs = {}
    user_attrs['objectclass'] = [b'top', b'person', b'organizationalPerson', b'user']
    user_attrs['cn'] = [b'cn']
    user_attrs['givenName'] = [b'givenname']
    user_attrs['sn'] = [b'sn']
    user_attrs['displayName'] = [b'displayName']
    user_attrs['mail'] = [b'mail']
    user_attrs['userPrincipalName'] = [b'userPrincipalName']
    user_attrs['sAMAccountname'] = [b'sam']
    user_attrs['name'] = [b'name']
    user_ldif = modlist.addModlist(user_attrs)

    ldap_client.add_s(user_dn, user_ldif)
```

this code gives me the error:

> ldap.INVALID_DN_SYNTAX: {'msgtype': 105, 'msgid': 2, 'result': 34, 'desc': 'Invalid DN syntax', 'ctrls': [], 'info': "00002081: NameErr: DSID-03050C55, problem 2003 (BAD_ATT_SYNTAX), data 0, best match of:\n\t'CN=TOTO Test,OU=ou_where_create,OU=users,OU=tree_of_ou,OU=FIM,DC=domain,DC=LAN'\n"}

I tried with other syntax for my attributes, without list [], without byte but with .encode(utf8)... but the error is no longer the same.
The problem must come from my user_dn but I don't see what.
Thanking you in advance for any help or clarification you can provide.
regards,

Comment: Does the DN syntax you're using match the DN of the existing objects in the same OU? (everything after the `CN=` part should be exactly the same.

Comment: thank you for your attention to my problem. Yes the whole tree after the CN exists except the name of the user I want to create (toto test). If I create the user manually in the ad and relaunch my script, it tells me that it already exists, I deduce that the path is correct.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but try not setting the `name` attribute. It will get set from the value in `cn`.

Comment: I just tried without the name attribute but I got the same error, invalid DN syntax and if I put an existing account name in the cn, I got the error already exists. I look with ldap3 suddenly, for the moment I manage to create a user. It's on the search and the behavior in case of an already existing user that I'm struggling but as it seems to work I'll probably start on that. Thanks again